# Specifying column name in a "references" migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-migrations

I want to make a `migration` in Rails, referencing another table. Usually, I would do something like:

```
add_column :post, :user, :references
```

This creates a column named `user_id` in `posts` table. But what if, instead of `user_id`, I want something like `author_id`? How can I do that?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Do it manually:

```
add_column :post, :author_id, :integer
```

but now, when you create the belongs_to statement, you will have to modify it, so now you have to call

```
def post
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'author_id'
end
```

Comment: Don't I have to add any index?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create an index in the migration.

Comment: Rails cheats - it doesn't really use indexes by default. Now if you want indexes (which are a great idea - despite the fact that rails will completely ignore them), than you can certainly add them. You will want to check out the guide I link for more info on migrations in general, and you may even end up putting calling SQL code directly in your migration. I would say ignore it, as it isn't a normal part of rails, you will get 0 performance out of it, as rails' default generated SQL queries take no advantage of it.

[link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: using `schema_plus` gem, `t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true, references: :match_categories` also worked for me in migration file.

Comment: I would suggest to use `bigint` instead of `integer` as it's the [default column type for primary keys for Rails 5.1+](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266)

Comment: It's probably worth noting, at this point, that ALL of this is dated, particularly since Rails5, which has better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 340):

## For Rails 5+

#### Initial Definition:

If you are defining your `Post` model table, you can set `references`, `index` and `foreign_key` in one line:

```rb
t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

---

#### Update Existing:

If you are adding references to an existing table, you can do this:

```rb
add_reference :posts, :author, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

---

<sup>**Note:** *The default value for `index` is true.*</sup>

Comment: Will the initial definition allow nulls?  If not, do you know the nullable alternative?

Comment: This definition allows `null`s. To not allow them, add the usual option `null: false`.

Comment: Thanks.  For the "Initial Definition", I think the "index: true" isn't necessary.  I get the same schema change with or without it.  Never mind; just saw your note at the end.

Comment: Doesn't `references` add the index automatically?

Comment: Yes, but I like being explicit.

Answer (score 262):

In **Rails 4.2+** you can also set [foreign keys](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys) in the db as well, [which is a great idea](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity).

For simple associations this can be done also on `t.references` adding `foreign_key: true`, but in this case you'll need two lines.

```
# The migration
add_reference :posts, :author, index: true
add_foreign_key :posts, :users, column: :author_id

# The model
belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is tagged Rails3, I'm happy to just help out

Comment: Ooh, I didn't notice that. Well, it's been very helpful to.me. :)

Comment: @ecoologic, just one thing you might want to add, add_foreign_key is only rails 4.2+. ;)

Comment: Is there a syntax for the has_many that goes along with this?

Comment: @JeffreyBasurto the column always goes on the `belong_to` part of the relation, I hope this answers your question

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `references: :users` option in the `add_reference` call. I don't see it documented in the docs and it seems to work on my end without it.

Comment: Looking at the source, it indeed doesn't do anything with an optional `references` argument. And I think the way it's set up it doesn't matter if there is not a table called `authors`, all it's doing is adding a column called `author_id`. It *does* matter if you want to create a foreign key constraint though, because it does try to use that as the table name then, so if you wanted to do that, you'd have to have a separate add_foreign_key statement.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the correction, I'm updating this right now. I can't remember where I got that from (it's been a few years). Thank you.

Answer (score 104):

In rails 4, when using postgresql and the [schema_plus](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus) gem you can just write

```
add_reference :posts, :author, references: :users
```

This will create a column `author_id`, which correctly refers to `users(id)`.

And in your model, you write

```
belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
```

Note, when creating a new table you can write it as follows:

```
create_table :things do |t| 
  t.belongs_to :author, references: :users 
end
```

> Note: the `schema_plus` gem in it's entirety is not compatible with rails 5+, but this functionality is offered by the gem [schema_auto_foreign_keys](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_auto_foreign_keys) (part of schema_plus) which is compatible with rails 5.

Comment: and if you are using `create_table`: `t.references :author, references: :users`

Comment: Adding @MichaelRadionov's comment to your answer would make it perfect.

Comment: I've been looking at the Rails 4.1 source, and I can't find any evidence that `:references` actually does anything.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have been using the `schema_plus` gem for ages, and it is actually adding that functionality. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: In Rails 6, it seems like the syntax `t.references :col_name, references: other_table_name` works without installing extra gems.

Answer (score 53):

If you aren't using a foreign key, then it doesn't matter what the actual table name of the other table is.

```
add_reference :posts, :author
```

**As of Rails 5**, if you're using a foreign key, you can specify the name of the other table in the foreign key options. (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21563 for discussion)

```
add_reference :posts, :author, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
```

Prior to Rails 5, you should add the foreign key as a separate step:

```
add_foreign_key :posts, :users, column: :author_id
```

Comment: Note that `rails g migration AddAuthorToPosts author:references` can't output this. You have to manually update the migration (see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/USAGE)

Answer (score -3):

**alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)** is very handy. 
Just create your model and the relationship:

```
rails g model Post title user:references
```

then edit the model and add an attribute alias with

```
alias_attribute :author, :user
```

After that you'll be able to run things like

```
Post.new(title: 'My beautiful story', author: User.first)
```

Comment: this does not work when you need to define multiple references to another model, e.g., post (author, editor)