# Specify column name in create_table in Rails migration belongs_to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

I am creating the following table:

```
create_table(:categories) do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: true
  t.uuid :uuid, unique: true, null: true, index: true
  t.string :kind, :limit => 32, null: false, index: true
  t.string :category, null: false, index: true
  t.datetime :deleted_at, null: true, index: true
  t.timestamps null: false, index: false

  t.index [:kind, :category], :unique => true
end
```

The first column is a foreign key and will by default be named "user_id". I want to create the column with the belongs_to but specify the column name as "created_by_user_id". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the foreign key column to `foreign_key` like this:

```
create_table(:categories) do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: 'created_by_user_id', index: true
  ...
end
```

Comment: Oddly this doesn't work for me. It still creates the column name as user_id. Rails 4.2.10

Comment: try adding this line: `add_foreign_key :categories, :users, column: :created_by_user_id` after the `t.belongs_to` as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577869/5636930

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution you are looking for is explicitly creating an `int` or `bigint` column, depending on your database.

So it will be something like:

```
create_table(:categories) do |t|
  t.integer :created_by_user_id, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: true
...
```

Comment: How do you specify the foreign_key is to the user_id on the Users table?

Comment: Rails does this via `belongs_to` inside model. `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "created_by_user_id"`