# Why did Rails 5 change "index" to "foreign key"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, primary-key, ruby-on-rails-5

If you had this in Rails 4:

```
t.references :event, index: true
```

Now you could use `foreign_key` instead of `index` in Rails 5. I don't quite understand WHY they decided to do this, since the functionality remains the same, what you're adding is an INDEX, not a FOREIGN KEY to that column.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question, the index option adds a database index, the foreign key one adds a database foreign key.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Rails 5 - when we reference a model, index on the `foreign_key` is automatically created.

Migration API has changed in Rails 5 -

Rails 5 has changed migration API because of which even though `null: false` options is not passed to timestamps when migrations are run then not null is automatically added for timestamps.

Similarly, we want indexes for referenced columns in almost all cases. So Rails 5 does not need references to have `index: true`. When migrations are run then index is automatically created.

As an example - (Copying from http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html)

When you run `rails g model Task user:references`

Rails 4 would generate

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And rails 5 would generate

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Very well detailled answer. BUT, what if for whatever reason, I don't want the reference to be indexed? Or was it still indexed implicitly in Rails 4 even if I only have `t.references :user, foreign_key: true` ? --- And now, I wonder why they didn't even omit `foreign_key: true` too.

Answer (score 18):

The `index` and `foreign_key` are different concepts, even if in Rails 5. So it's wrong to say the rails 5 changed “index” to “foreign key”.

The change from Rails 4 to Rails 5 is that the `index` option defaults to `true`, so you don't need to set it explicitly.

Method [add_reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) in rails 4.2.5

> :index
>
> Add an appropriate index. Defaults to false.

---

Method [add_reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) in rails 5.2

> :index
>
> Add an appropriate index. Defaults to true. See add_index for usage of this option.

That's why when you generate the `references` in rails 5 migration, you didn't see the `index: true`, because it's default.

Answer (score 5):

[`foreign_key`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key) and [`index`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) are completely different things (as you may judge from their names).

So nothing is being changed, you still can use two.

You can check out [these docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for some more info on establishing associations in migrations.