# has many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a table of users in which I have 2 types of users interacting with my app. One is the 'Seller' and the other is 'Buyer'. 
I have also 3 other tables as Products, Shop and Joins. Joins and shop have the polymorphic association between them.

How can I differentiate the users at join table ???

**User Class:**

```
has_many :joins
has_many :products, through: :joins
```

**Product Class:**

```
has_many :joins
has_many :users, through: :join
```

**Shop Class:**

```
has_many :joins, :as => :joinable
```

**Join Class:**

```
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :joinable, :polymorphic => true
```

Comment: Don't name your table or model joins unless you really want to shoot yourself and any poor sucker that has to work on your code in the foot. Just imagine looking at `JOINS "joins" ON "joins.id" = "joined.join_id"`.

Comment: Do you really need this polymorphic relationship (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)? Why not a flag in user model? For example `is_seller:boolean`, `is_buyer:boolean`? Then add `seller_id` and `buyer_id` to the join table (change the name of the join table!) both referred to `User`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417320/scaffolding-activerecord-two-columns-of-the-same-data-type